# Delphi: play memorystream in wmp activex

Tags: delphi, memorystream, wmp

I'm new to this site and I hope someone can help me with my problem.
I am using a Delphi language. And I would want to play a memorystream to windowsmediaplayer ActiveX. Is this possible? If it is, can someone give me a hint or something.. sample code maybe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Delphi 2009, but earlier version of Delphi didn't support this with the TMediaPlayer component. What you could do is write the MemoryStream to a temporary file, then have the TMediaPlayer load that file. That's going to be the easiest solution, though admittedly not ideal.

Comment: Tim, your suggestion will be my last resort. I already have a code on that one. But what the hell, I'm trying to break my mind here.lol! Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Not a free solution, but there is a commercial SDK, BoxedAppSDK, which allows you to access in-memory files as if they were on disk.   One of their samples includes a media player accessing a file from memory.

http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/

Comment: tikinoa, this is exactly what I am looking for. Too bad this is not free.lol! Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago Nils Haeck posted an example on how to play an **avi** from a **TMemoryStream** on [NLDelphi](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10516). He couldn't get it to play **mp3**'s though. For that you should be looking at other solutions, like [Un4Seen Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html)

The code:
[playfrommemory.zip](http://www.nldelphi.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=1191&d=1066436669)

Comment: thnks for the code wouter. But what i really want is to use the windows media player activex to play from a memorystream.. although I think it is possible to modify this code. I'll try. Thanks a lot